# Connecting an app created in cordova to API build in .net within a local server using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

How can i connect my android app build in Cordova to API's built in .net using c# within local server created by visual studio ?

Can any one help ?

Comment: Do you have a Content-Security-Policy entry specifying localhost yet?

Comment: what is that as m just learning i didnt knw much about it ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://content-security-policy.com/